# Scientific computing: academic research versus industrial skills

Tags: phd, career-path, early-career

I am trying to evaluate the difference between two professional figures in the field of scientific computing, they are called Alice and Bob:

- Alice has earned a PhD in applied mathematics at a top 10 university, she has two publications in rather good journals, and had to write a certain number of python programs to prototype her findings. She has limited industrial experience acquired through a 7 months internship at the end of her master's, where she saw some basics of Fortran/C++ and parallel computing. Her area of expertise is computational mechanics and finite elements - she has developed some new algorithmic approaches there - but not how to write high performant and efficient low level code
- Bob has earned an industrial PhD from a university ranked 300/400 in the world, working full time for a well-known scientific computing company. He has two small conference papers where he mainly applied existing methods to his case and compared their performance. He constantly worked with Fortran/C++, parallel computing and low level code. The area of expertise is computational electromagnetism with finite elements, but the focus was implementing mathematical algorithms into a commercial software, and make them fast and robust

Unfortunately, the company of Bob cannot hire him at the end of the PhD, and he finds himself competing with Alice for an opening at another well known scientific computing company, offering a position as a scientific software developer in C++/Fortran, in industry.

Who has higher chances of being offered the position?

The application area of the job offer might be computational mechanics, electromagnetism, or fluid dynamics...

How does industry consider skills, experience and formal education?

*Disclaimer*: [cross posted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42996/research-profile-vs-coding-expertise-for-scientific-programming-career?noredirect=1#comment84847_42996) on Computational Science, where I was advised to also post to Academia Stack exchange.

Comment: @Nobody The company is not able to open a new position for Bob (e.g. lack of money)

Comment: @Nobody It was covered by research funds from the government, not possible

Comment: What  Industry wants are skills and _real_ experience. Alice _has limited industrial experience_. What about Bob ?

Comment: He has I guess lots of coding, in low level languages. A lot of debugging. Precision and methodicity. Designing code that others have to interface with. @Nobody
To name a few, there are certainly more: he is used to working in a team and so on

Comment: Bob would get it if I were the hiring manager. Unfortunately, I am not the hiring person. My words don't count.

Comment: *Who has higher chances of being offered the position?

The application area of the job offer might be computational mechanics, electromagnetism, or fluid dynamics. I am curious to see how the answer might change.*
It is impossible to answer. All research centre do research, all companies work for profit. Then there are too many varieties of goals and way to get to the goal. A company developing injector for diesel fuel would have a different interests in fluid mechanics with respect to an insurance company interested in climate model, i.e. fluid mechanics.

Comment: Alice and Bob are two different persons, with different interests ... you are asking something similar to "what is the best way to spend 2 hours with friends, eating <insert your preferred food> or going to watch <insert preferred show or sport or exhibition>?"
It depends on you and on the friends you have, there cannot be a general answer.

Comment: Could you edit out the ending part ... <del> *I am curious to see how the answer might change.

I expect that there is no definite answer, as the situation might depend on the recruiters, the specific position etc... But maybe I have overlooked one aspect or the other and perhaps, Alice is much more appealing than Bob, or viceversa.* </del>. Can you conclude with ... > What/How does industry consider skills, experience and formal education?

Answer (score 1):

1. Bob will never be let go by his company, after they trained them to be the (world leading?) top expert in their specific application.
2. Both Bob and Alice are extremely competitive candidates and BOTH will find employment swiftly.

You are likely a fresh graduate thinking about your next move. It sounds like you are extremely risk averse and afraid of becoming jobless. With these qualifications that is not very rational, no matter your choice.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, both will get an interview, and the respective personality of Bob and Alice will be the deciding factor.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a recruiter or industry person so I doubt my opinion holds too much weight.

Bob has experience and, presumably, solid references from his previous industry job. I think he also has perfectly acceptable qualifications otherwise. If his hard skills and experience are a better match for the job I would think he is in the running. The caveat here is that it is possible (and this happens literally all the time) that a recruiter or hiring manager may be swayed by the shiny credentials of Alice and overlook her lack of industry experience. My guess is that both are really on pretty equal (although different) footing and the final decision would come down to what the company was looking for, how the interview went, how each candidate fits with the team, etc.

It's literally impossible to know past that. It could be that the boss graduated from Bob's university. Or it could be that there is a mid-level manage who is a snob and only wants people with prestigious degrees. It could be that there is a third person that has both a prestigious degree AND years of relevant experience.

Comment: What is your experience with hiring managers in particular?
Note that my field is pretty small: there are not many applicants per job position, it is possible that screening is done more carefully than when many applicants are present

Comment: I am not a hiring manager, if that's what you mean. This is just like, my opinion man.

Comment: I was rather meaning the "happens literally all the time". I was curious on which stories (personal or not) you may have there. Or to expand on this point.

Comment: *my field is pretty small: there are not many applicants per job position, it is possible that screening is done more carefully than when many applicants are present*

It is actually the contrary: since there are few applicants per position, the screening will be performed on a case-by-case basis and not on rigid absolute criteria, with criteria 100% contingent to the current project/business/team situation, one day Alice is the best fit and 6 months later for exactly the same advertised position Bob is the best fit.